# Minecraft 1.12 crashes at start

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When I start Minecraft it crashes, and I get this nativelog:

```
Set run directory to C:\Program Files\Minecraft
Native Launcher Version: 1321
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro
Application Hash: d026a01a83aeaec4111e8c7430ad89b21f3a30f3
Application Data directory: C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Roaming/.minecraft
Executable Path: MinecraftLauncher.exe
App Directory dir: C:\Program Files\Minecraft
Start dir: C:/Users/Gebruiker/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft
Launcher dir: C:/Program Files/Minecraft/game
TmpDir dir: C:/Program Files/Minecraft/tmp
(Optional) Java Launcher hash: 
Java Version: 1.8.0_25
x64: 0
LauncherConfiguration from: http://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/launcher.json
Downloaded config
Native launcher is current
Native launcher is current
Detected previous run with new launcher, format of C:/Users/Gebruiker/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/launcher_profiles.json is 2
Using new launcher as self upgrade has been detected.
Launcher library is up to date with hash ec064f05257ba720c432bce019329ec56417a61f
Check to see if we can run the launcher
Native launcher is current
Starting launcher.dll with C:\Program Files\Minecraft\runtime\jre-x32\1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
Found SetDllDirectoryW in kernel32.dll!
Added C:\Program Files\Minecraft\game to DLL search path
Running launcher!
Launcher ended with 0
```

How can I get it to run properly?

Answer (score 1):

This is known to be a problem with your computer.
– Update your graphics card drivers. (Do not rely on automatic updates)
– If you are using Java arguments to increase the amount of memory, please reduce it to the default 512MB.
– If that did not help, please use the community support link below.

From a similar crash report from Mojang bug report.

https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-7638?attachmentViewMode=list

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling the game. Restarting a PC fixes many problems, so reinstalling a game might do the same.